# migrate varchar column to jsonb array

Tags: postgresql

I have a `varchar` field that has simple strings in it, such as `apple` and `banana`. I am simply trying to change the column to a `JSONB[]` column, and the values so they look like `["apple"]` and `["banana"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb[]` almost never makes sense, if at all, use `jsonb`. If you did use `jsonb[]` your  values would look like `{"[\"banana\"]"}`, not `["banana"]`.

To convert a single `varchar` value to a JSONB value that is an array (**not** an array of JSONB values) you can use:

```
to_jsonb(array[the_column])
```

This can be used as part of an ALTER TABLE statement:

```
alter table the_table
  alter column the_column 
  type jsonb using to_jsonb(array[the_column]);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a20753808727ce48c7e3e53b63ae175e)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for explaining re jsonb vs jsonb[]. I tried a million different configurations of something similar but never quite got there, apparently.